# Need of Function overloading?

Tags: c++, oop

I am wondering if a programmer has to write different calls for overloaded function then why shouldn't programmer use different names for the calling the function.
eg. area functions using Function overloading are

```
area(int a){ cout<< " area of square"<< a*a; }

area( int a, int b) { cout<< " area of rectangle"<< a*b; }
```

Instead of above overloaded function I can write areaSquare and areaRectangle.

So why do we need Function overloading.

Comment: Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading

Comment: We don't.  But it's often very convenient.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343913/what-is-the-use-advantage-of-function-overloading

Comment: Would you really want to have to write `cout.output_string(" area of square").output_int(a*a);` and have to change `output_int` if you change `a`'s type, or do you find it convenient that `operator<<` is overloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Because sometimes it's hard to find many different meaningful names for a single action.

For example, think about function `abs`, do you really want this:

```
int    abs_int   (int    x);
float  abs_float (float  x);
double abs_double(double x);
```

or this:

```
int    abs(int    x);
float  abs(float  x);
double abs(double x);
```

It's up to you, choose one of them.

Comment: Well the OP has suggested a very general scheme for finding such names.

Answer (score 0):

For naturalism.

Function overloading can be a convenient and intuitive feature of Object Oriented Programming.
If you want to find out the area of triangle, there are at least three measurements (except giving only all 3 angles) are required to find out its area.

In that case do you feel it is natural to put different names for methods with different parameters all with the same goal that is returning its area? No.

Given three sides:

```
public static double getTriangleArea(int sideA,int sideB,int sideC){
                   //abstract it..
                   return area;
       }
```

Given 2 sides and angle between them:

```
public static double getTriangleArea(int sideA,int sideB,double angleAB){
                          //abstract it..
                       return area;
}
```

**Edit:**
 A better example due to the comment by hvd

```
public double getDouble(String doubleString){
              //abstract it
               return doubleValue;
}



 public double getDouble(int input){

              return getDouble((Integer)input);
}

public double getDouble(float input){

              return getDouble((Float)input);
}
//etc...
```

All the best.

Comment: @jogojapan I edited.....

Comment: @MM. Of course but the OP wanted to know about FO

Comment: That's a really bad candidate for overloading, that means `getTriangleArea(1, 1, 1)` and `getTriangleArea(1., 1., 1.)` do something completely different.

Comment: @hvd +1 for slapping point....

Comment: @hvd edited to reflect that....

Comment: @MM. that's my fault I didn't see it at first