# Return different types from c++ functions

Tags: c++, overloading

Ok, so I am struggling with the following:

I have a class (`A`), which holds a `vector<B>` (a vector for Qt) of some other classes (`B`). The class `B` has a property, let's say `p` and also has a name.

For one case, I would like to get a listing of the `B` objects that are to be found in class `A` which have the `p` property set, and for another case I would like to get a list of the names of the `B` objects that have the property set.

And most of all, I would like to have these two functions to be called the same :)

So, something like:

```
class A
{
public:
    QVector<B*> B_s_with_p() { ... }

    QStringList B_s_with_p() { ... }
};
```

but I don't want to have a helper parameter to overload the methods (yes, that would be easy), and the closest I have got is a method with a different name ... which works, but it's ugly. Templates don't seem to work either.

Is there a way using todays' C++ to achieve it?

Comment: Instead of returning by value, why not pass argument by reference to be populated?

Comment: Why do you want two functions that do different things to have the same name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't functions be overloaded by return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331837/why-cant-functions-be-overloaded-by-return-type) with some workarounds [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value), though I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: You can't do this the way you want (see the already given answers). To make it clearer: which function shall the compiler choose when you call `B_s_with_p`? None of both is better than the other. Shall the compiler make a non-deterministic choice? Throw dice?

Comment: Your options are to change the method name, add a second `out` parameter, or use templates.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Well, it could see how it is being used :) I suppose the designers figured that was too complicated.

Comment: @0A0D: That would only work in some cases. It won't if a) you call `(void)B_s_with_p()` or b) you call `class XY xy = B_s_with_p()` where there are two overloads for `XY::XY`.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Yes, that's why its too ambiguous to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cheat would be to use a reference to `QVector<B*>` or `QStringList` as an argument instead of a return type. That way you can overload `B_s_with_p` as normal. I guess you don't consider that a valid option.

Comment: That's no cheat but rather the usual way to deal with this kind of situation (if you really MUST have the same function name, that is)

Comment: I called it a cheat because I assume this is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

Only the signature is used to overload methods. That means the return type can't be use to overload.

You have to use different methods names or manage your return value with a parameter :

```
class A
{
public:
    void B_s_with_p(QVector<B*>&);
    void B_s_with_p(QStringList&);
};
```

`B_s_with_p()` could use a template type as parameter.

Comment: Yep, standard practice. It satisfies the "must have the same name" requirement of the question. And if you were looking for a way to ignore the return value, you'd use pointer arguments instead of references and check for `nullptr` before assigning to them. But in this case it doesn't look like the functions would ever be called just for their side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that having two different names for *two different sets of functionality* is ugly? That's *exactly* what you should be doing to delineate the different return types here.

Another alternative is to have *just* the function that returns an object, and then create a `names_of` method that you pass the list of `B` objects and it returns the list of names.

Answer (score -1):

Check your design .. Overloaded functions are one which have similar funcionality but differnt argument types .. So check why you want to

```
I would like to have these two functions to be called the same
```

refer to :[What is the use/advantage of function overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343913/what-is-the-use-advantage-of-function-overloading)

The benefit of overloading  is consistency in the naming of functions which perform the same task, just with different parameters.