# Overloading Mehods

Tags: oop

In Overloading the different parameter takes same memory space or different memory space? IF it doesnot create same memory space so whats was the advantage of using overloading method we can create the method with different name?

Comment: What do you mean by "same memory space"? Are you asking about formal parameters to a method (which usually take zero space in most OOP languages I know) or actual parameters in a call? The most common advantages cited for method overloading are readability, expressiveness, and ease of use for the API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use/advantage of function overloading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343913/what-is-the-use-advantage-of-function-overloading)

Answer (score 0):

Overloading isn't to save space. Obviously overloaded functions with different parameters can have different space allocation in stack when called. It's just an object oriented approach. It allows you to define more than one definition for your function. [image: This example would help]

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm